# Xcode 12 / iOS14 Widget "@main and must provide a main static function" error

Tags: swiftui, widget, ios14, xcode12, widgetkit

Using Xcode 12 trying to create Widget app extension to my project.

Upon creating new Widget target I am getting the following error:

```
'Widget' is annotated with @main and must provide a main static function of type () -> Void or () throws -> Void.
```

[image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You are using name `Widget`, there is already a protocol called `Widget` in `SwiftUI` framework.

You should use some other name but if you really want to, add module name at start like `SwiftUI.Widget`

```
@main
struct Widget: SwiftUI.Widget {
    private let kind: String = "Widget"

    public var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider(), placeholder: PlaceholderView()) { entry in
            WidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Also @main
struct SwiftUIApp: SwiftUI.App

Comment: This is the exact correct answer - You should not create a widget extension called "Widget" which will lead to this error.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone looking to fix the AppDelegate issue when turning on Mac for an iOS14 project - please consult : [iOS Xcode 12.0 Swift 5 'AppDelegate' is annotated with @main and must provide a main static function of type () -> Void or () throws -> Void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971819/ios-xcode-12-0-swift-5-appdelegate-is-annotated-with-main-and-must-provide-a)

The fix is to change "@main" to "@UIApplicationMain"

Comment: For SwiftUI projects: `@UIApplicationMain may only be used on 'class' declarations`

Comment: So, to fix that need to use Xcode 12.2 and fresh beta of macOS 11

Answer (score 3):

I got this exact error with the following code:

```
@main
struct NotesApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem was I named my app logic class `App`.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error with this code :

```
import WidgetKit

@main
struct WidgetSale: Widget {
    let kind: String = "widgetSale"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            widgetSaleEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}
```

I solve it by importing swiftUI at the top of the file :

```
import SwiftUI
```

Comment: Already have `import SwiftUI`, but the error still appears.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had some code this file:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct FooWidgetExtension: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        SomeWidget()
    }
}

private struct SomeWidget: Widget {
    init() {}

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        EmptyWidgetConfiguration()
    }
}
```

And the issue was actually you need to have an `import WidgetKit` as well. The `main` function must be defined as an extension in that module.