# iOS Xcode 12.0 Swift 5 'AppDelegate' is annotated with @main and must provide a main static function of type () -> Void or () throws -> Void

Tags: xcode, macos, swift5

In my Xcode 12.0 using Swift 5 and Catalina 10.15.5: When I tick Mac as deployable target (Apple Project Catalyst), and click Runs, it gives me an error showing:

```
'AppDelegate' is annotated with @main and must provide a main static function of type () -> Void or () throws -> Void.
```

[image]

Can't find anything on Internet... I have checked my codes and nothing's wrong and it can be run on iOS devices and simulators. Debug log is empty (duhh...)

Anyone facing this issue?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Change `@main` to `@UIApplicationMain` and ignore any resulting warnings.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12-release-notes

> A newly-created iOS project using the Swift language may no longer build after enabling Mac Catalyst. (67885114)
>
> Workaround: Replace the `@main` annotation on the App Delegate with `@UIApplicationMain`.

Answer (score 2):

The Xcode 12.1 (or less) does not include the macOS 11 SDK, which the new SwiftUI app cycle requires for Mac apps.

You will have to install the **Xcode 12.2 beta (candidate release)** and use that until macOS 11 ships.