# @UIApplicationMain may only be used on 'class' declarations error when using SwiftUI App Lifecycle on Mac

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode12

If you create a new SwiftUI app in Xcode 12 and use the SwiftUI App Lifecycle this struct is generated... When you build for Mac it's generating this error. Apple has noted `@main` is an issue in their Xcode 12 release notes (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12-release-notes)

People have discussed workaround for `AppDelegate` class.. but it does not work for SwiiftUI App Lifecycle (which you select when you create a new SwiftUI App project for iPhone)([iOS Xcode 12.0 Swift 5 'AppDelegate' is annotated with @main and must provide a main static function of type () -> Void or () throws -> Void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971819/ios-xcode-12-0-swift-5-appdelegate-is-annotated-with-main-and-must-provide-a)

Does anyone have a workaround for this yet, other than switching to AppDelegate and SceneDelegate.

```
//@main
@UIApplicationMain // @UIApplicationMain may only be used on 'class' declarations
struct MyApp: App { // Cannot find type 'App' in scope
    var body: some Scene { // Cannot find type 'Scene' in scope
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

This is the error I get when I use the `@main` attribute:

`'MyApp' is annotated with @main and must provide a main static function of type () -> Void or () throws -> Void.`

I can add the static main function part but it still doesn't resolve the can't find app in scope or scene in scope issues.

```
 @main
 struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
        }
    }

    static func main() -> Void {
    
    }
}
```

EDIT EDIT:

Note this does not resolve my issue... It still complains about the `@main` attribute [SwiftUI app life cycle iOS14 where to put AppDelegate code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538110/swiftui-app-life-cycle-ios14-where-to-put-appdelegate-code)

Comment: @Asperi right I understand that... But you can't compile SwiftUI App Lifecycle apps since Xcode12 GM release.. During the betas I had no problem with the `@main` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Xcode 12.2 and fresh beta of macOS 11